# $y=e^x\sin x$; find all points where slope of tangent line equals 0

Tags: derivatives

I have the derivative already. Using the product rule, I got $e^{2}\sin x+e^{2}\cos x$. I can't figure out how to find all the points without graphing it.

Comment: That's not the derivative of $e^x \sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

We need $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0\implies e^x(\sin x+\cos x)=0$$

As for finite real $x,e^x>0$

$$\implies\sin x+\cos x=0\iff\tan x=-1=-\tan\dfrac\pi4=\tan\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)$$

$x=n\pi-\dfrac\pi4$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Maybe you want to say any !